# How to sort table's column based on value of other column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Table from A:C column, in the column H, I have the same value on the column B in diffrent order, how to sort table based on the column H ?

```
Public Sub ReportSorting()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim sRange As Range
    Dim kRange  As Variant
    Dim nSort As Long

    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

    Set sRange = sht.Range("H2:H" & LastRow)

    'Read values into array from range ActiveSheet
    kRange = sRange.Value

    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=kRange
    nSort = Application.CustomListCount

    sht.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    sht.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1:B" & LastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:=nSort, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With sht.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:C" & LastRow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = True
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

I'm getting

> Error 1004: The mothod Add AddCustomList for the object Application has failure!

A:C table name is: Req and H is out of the table.

```
A      B    C    ...   H
PID   ID   Name        SID
-     001  AAA         001
001   002  BBB         002
004   003  CCC         004
      004  DDD         003  
....
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation the [Application.AddCustomList method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.addcustomlist) the error is pretty clear:

> If the list that you are trying to add already exists, this method throws a run-time error 1004.

So obviosly you try to add a list that already exists.

Comment: i tried also to  CustomOrder:=nSort to CustomOrder:=kRange  and also didnt worked

Answer (score 0):

the Application.AddCustomList method can hold only string and if you try to add numbers (Range) as in the example above , getting error!

I tried a simple tricks and add a helper column (from ID) and add also string "abc" in both column's values (D and H) like the following:

```
 A     B    C      D    ...   H
PID   ID   Name   HID        SID
      001  AAA   abc001     abc001
001   002  BBB   abc002     abc002
004   003  CCC   abc003     abc004
      004  DDD   abc004     abc003
```

and sort D column:

```
sht.Sort.SortFields.Clear
sht.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D1:D" & LastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:=nSort, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With sht.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:D" & LastRow)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = True
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

now it is working ;)